# Difference between bind(Foo.class).to(Bar.class) vs bind(Foo.class).toInstance(new Bar())

Tags: guice

What's the difference between `bind(Foo.class).to(Bar.class)` and `bind(Foo.class).toInstance(new Bar())`;

Also, would fields be injected properly with the latter method of calling the constructor `new Bar()`?

Comment: Fields will be injected properly in both cases (see https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#automatic-injection).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`bind(Foo.class).to(Bar.class)` is a [linked binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/LinkedBindings): you're telling Guice "whenever someone asks for a Foo, give them a Bar instead". You're not telling Guice how to create a Bar; this implies that there's an @Inject-annotated or public zero arg constructor and that you're allowing Guice to do everything it normally does *including field injection*. You're also not telling Guice whether to memoize the Bar instance and keep it around, meaning it will create a new Bar every time. (Note that this doesn't preclude you from `bind(Bar.class).to(Baz.class)` or `bind(Bar.class).toInstance(new Baz())` if you wanted to; without one of those you're technically letting `Bar` be an [implicit or JIT binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings).)

`bind(Foo.class).toInstance(new Bar())` is an [instance binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings). You're telling Guice "whenever someone asks for a Foo, give them *this* Bar instead". Guice doesn't ever try to create a Bar, so it doesn't try to inject constructor parameters, and it also doesn't ever try to create a different Bar: you always get the same one. *UPDATE: Thanks Tavian, I'd forgotten that [automatic injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#automatic-injection) do allow field injection on toInstance bindings.* Note that none of this affects injection requests for Bar, just Foo.

So, the former allows injection and creates a new instance every time, and the latter lets you create instances manually and returns the same instance every time. Those can also be two separate decisions:

- To always return the same instance, you can mark the class with `@Singleton`, or make your binding `.in(Singleton.class)`. See [Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) for more details and options. Guice creates the instance, so you have access to field injections.
- To let you create instances manually without field injection (but allowing for calls to static factory methods or custom initializer methods), [bind to a Provider](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings) or [create a @Provides method](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods). Guice won't inject fields, because you've taken the creation on yourself.

  Those provider/@Provides bindings can also be made Singleton, which is similar to `toInstance` above, but doesn't require you to create your instance at injector creation time.

Comment: One more difference is that method interception in Guice only works when you let guice create the instance for you (regardless of scope binding). See limitations here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP

Comment: Well explained, especially the slight difference between `@Provides` and `toInstance`